# XSLT using value-of to retrieve text from node with attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am interested in retrieving `foo` from the following XML:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c num="2">foo</c>
    <c num="3">bar</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Using XSLT+XPATH, I'm attempting to do something similar to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="a/b/c/@num=2/current()">
```

But I don't think that will retrieve `foo` properly. Is there a better way of going about with this?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?  Experiment before posting so you can ask a specific question. BTW, it should be `a/b/c[@num=2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/a/b/c[@num='2']" />
```

Complete example:

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/a/b/c[@num='2']" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
  <b> 
    <c num="2">foo</c>
    <c num="3">bar</c>
  </b>
</a>
```